# If $f:M\rightarrow N$ is $C^{\infty}$, bijective, and everywhere non-singular, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds

I am not able to solve this problem:

> Prove that if $f:M\rightarrow N$ is $C^{\infty}$, one-to-one, onto, and everywhere non-singular, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

This $f$ is a diffeomorphism $\iff$ $df$ is surjective everywhere, right? Then how to proceed?

Comment: My guess is that he's referring to this particular $f$, in the last line.

Comment: Ah, good point Dylan.

Comment: @Zev But it's a good thing to point out! I was typing out a comment to the same effect until I saw yours. I'll try to make it clearer in the edit. To Mex: If you are truly under the impression that for a general smooth map $M \to N$, surjectivity of the derivative at all points means that the map is a diffeomorphism, then you should tell us.

Comment: Since $f$ is a bijective smooth map it is a diffeomorphism iff $f^{-1}$ is smooth. This is guaranteed by the non-singularity condition , which means that the differential $T_mf:T_mM\to T_{f(m)}N$  is invertible at all $m\in M$.

Comment: Exactly. As Georges points out this is an application of the Inverse Function Theorem and doesn't require you to worry about $df$ being surjective everywhere.

Comment: Can I ask whether or not these problems are homework? In the past day you've asked questions ranging from confusion about the definition of differentiable structure on $\mathbb{R}$ to flows on manifolds. Are these review questions for a final or qual or something? Are you self-studying? It would be easier to know how to answer this string of questions if we knew more background.

Comment: Matt, I am self studying the book by FW Warner, and I am in first Chapter Now, solving problems also.

Comment: @Mex I loved that book once I had thoroughly gone through Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds because of how succinctly the material was presented. Can I recommend supplementing Warner with Lee because Lee is incredibly thorough presenting lots of examples, motivation, and intuition.

Comment: Dear Matt, Iam simply pleased and delighted at your suggestion.Collecting Lee and starting reading it :)